In a Baire space, every meager subset has dense complement
I have the following defintion for a Baire space:
"A topological space with the property that every countable intersection of dense open subsets is dense"
So here's my proof:
Let's say $F$ is meager, so $F=\bigcup_nU_n$ where $U_i$ is a nowhere dense (i.e. $\bar{U_i} $ has a dense complement for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$).
Now, $F^c=(\bigcup_nU_n)^c=\bigcap_nU_n^c$ and, since $U\subseteq \bar{U} \iff U^c \supseteq \bar{U}^c$, we get that $\bigcap_n{U_n^c} \supseteq\bigcap_n{\bar{U_n}}^c$
From the definition of Baire space we get that $\bigcap_n{\bar{U_n}}^c$ is dense in X hence $F^c=\bigcap_n{U_n}^c$ is dense as well.
Is this reasonament correct? Thanks!

In the first paragraph, I presume you meant every countable intersection of dense open subsets is dense, instead of countable union? Other than that, there’s no issue with the proof.

True, I'll change it right away, thanks
